# CakePHP 3- Showing all error and buildRules messages in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have this Model/Table/UsersProfilesTable.php where I have specified all the error messages and buildRules.

My intention is to list all the validation errors in the controller while attempting to save the data.

The code is mentioned below.

```
 // Model/Table/UsersProfilesTable.php 

 class UserProfilesTable extends Table{

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){

        $validator  =   new Validator();

        $validator
            ->notEmpty("first_name","First name cannot be empty.")
            ->requirePresence("first_name")
            .......
            ->notEmpty("email", "Email cannot be empty.")
            ->requirePresence("email")
            ->add( "email", "email",[
                "rule" => ["email", true],
                "message" => "Enter a valid e-mail."
            ]);



        return $validator;  
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules){

        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email'], 'Email should be unique'));

        return $rules;
    }
```

---

```
    //UsersController.php

      $user =   $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

      if($this->Users->save($user)){
        // Success msg
      }

      if($user->errors()){
         // This shows all the error messages except the one specified in the  buildRules for unique email.
         pr($user->errors()); 
      }
```

Can anyone please come up with a way in which I can list all the validation errors including the message specified in the buildRules method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Peace! xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that validation is a 2 phase process, first all the validatiton rules are checked (during marshalling - i.e. `patchEntity()`), only if they pass are the rules in buildRules are used. This means that the unique email rule will not be run until the standard validation rules all pass.

If you need immediate feedback for email uniqueness you can also add a validation rule for email uniqueness in the validator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to force Cake to check the rules even if validation fails:

```
$this->Users->checkRules($user);
```