# Validate against not edited properties

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an entity (Tour) that goes through some sort of sign-off process during it's lifetime.

When it's created, a startdate and enddate have to be specified as well as a deadline for signing up. All these properties are validated against each other (e.g. startdate has to be in the future, enddate has to be equal to or after the startdate, the deadline date has to be before the startdate, etc.).

When creating a new tour, this is simple to validate because all the dates are posted using the respective form. At a later stage in the process, however, only the deadline date may be changed, the startdate and enddate are already fixed. This poses the problem that the startdate does no longer belong to the posted data but the deadline has still to be valid in respect to the startdate.

How would I best access the startdate of the entity being edited in order to validate the deadline date?

I was thinking so far about:

- Loading the entity in the validation rule using the posted entity id. I don't like this approach because I have several such validations and each would then load the entity independently of each other.
- Altering the posted data to include the startdate from the original entity. This would provide the startdate for all the validation rules needing it but would alter the posted data which could cause problems further down the line.

Do you have any other suggestions? Is there maybe a hook that I can implement in order to inject something into the validation context and provide the entity with the startdate this way?

Comment: You should not do this as a validation, but rather as a rule. Validation is for checking basic things like data types (e.g. that what was entered is actually a date, with all three fields set, and not Feb 30 or Apr 31). Rules are for ensuring that data conforms to your business logic (e.g. start date is before deadline date). Rules are passed the entire patched entity, so you will always have all the data, both new and previously saved, available to you at that time.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you for your suggestion! I gave it a try and it works perfectly. If you want to create an answer based on your comment i'd accept it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I converted more validations to application rules and noticed the following problem: As long as any validation is not successful, the application rules will not be executed and therefore some of the errors show up only as soon as the validation passes which is not very user friendly... Any suggestions on that one?

Comment: That's a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251285/cakephp-3-showing-all-error-and-buildrules-messages-in-controller). :-)